# A task was canceled Exception when trying to upload file to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-core

**A task was canceled exception** is thrown when Im trying to call **fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync** to upload a file i S3. I'm using dot net core 2.0 and trying to Upload file to S3.What is that i'm doing wrong in the below code?
Is is something to do with Timeout? If so how to set time for s3 bucket? or Do I have to set some properties on S3 bucket?

Below is my controller code:

```
 public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        private AmazonS3Client _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1);
        private string _bucketName = "fileupload";//this is my Amazon Bucket name
        private static string _bucketSubdirectory = String.Empty;
        private string uploadWithKeyName = "testFile";

        public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }

        [HttpPost("UploadExcelData")]
        public async Task PostExcelData()
        {
            var files = Request.Form.Files;
            var stringVal = Request.Form.Keys;
            long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                            .Parse(formFile.ContentDisposition)
                            .FileName
                            .TrimStart().ToString();
                    filename = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $@"\uploads" + $@"\{formFile.FileName}";
                    size += formFile.Length;
                    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
                    {
                        formFile.CopyTo(fs);
                        fs.Flush();
                    }//these code snippets saves the uploaded files to the project directory

                  await UploadToS3(filename);//this is the method to upload saved file to S3

                }
            }
          //  return Ok();
        }
        public async Task UploadToS3(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new
                    TransferUtility(_s3Client);

                string bucketName;


                if (_bucketSubdirectory == "" || _bucketSubdirectory == null)
                {
                    bucketName = _bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
                }
                else
                {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
                    bucketName = _bucketName + @"/" + _bucketSubdirectory;
                }


                // 1. Upload a file, file name is used as the object key name.
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, uploadWithKeyName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload 1 completed");


            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                                  s3Exception.InnerException);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown error", ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How about starting with posting the exact exception in question?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to pass the credentials :
private AmazonS3Client _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(DynamoDbCRUD.Credentials.AccessKey,DynamoDbCRUD.Credentials.SecretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1);

This line works fine.